# AttributeError at 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'

Tags: django

When i click vote button I got this error AttributeError at /polls/2/vote/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'. When i tried to vote for any poll. This is my results.html file
I am using django==3.2 and python 3.8

This is my results.html

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
    {% if error_message %}
        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote" >
</form>
```

and this is my vote view function of polls app
It always shows Exception in line number 4 of the code

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.Post['choice'])

    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice"})

    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: Typo: `request.Post` must be `request.POST`... (Python is case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks abdul it's working